# Creating universal distribution group in exchange through Java

Tags: java, .net, api, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

I need to create universal distribution groups in exchange server 2010 programmatically through Java. I tried to look but most API's are mail box specific and create groups within the mailbox. Or I have to use Power shell cmdlets. I am wondering if there is any possible solutions for Java or do i have to use .NET?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all Exchange administration is done through PowerShell now. Even when programming in .NET, you need to run PowerShell cmdlets to do anything with Exchange. I had to do that when I wrote a service in C# to create mailboxes for new users (we're running 2010 as well).

So if you want to do this, you'll need to run PowerShell with Java.

This might help (I have no experience with it; I just found it in a Google search): https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell

To really make things a pain, to get the Exchange PowerShell module installed, you have to install the Exchange management tools, which is part of the Exchange installation (you only select the management tools in the setup). You'll have to do that on any machine your app will run on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes jPowerShell was one of the option, but for that I have to create some sort of socket connection to my Exchange domain or proxy  since jPowershell is limited to local powershell, which i was hoping to avoid. Yes i have Exchange management tools installed already.